# Joining many tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to get my head around this SQL question:
 A database for a hotel chain contains the following tables:

```
    Hotel(HotelNo, HotelName, City)   
    Room(RoomNo, HotelNo, Type, Price)  
    Booking(HotelNo, GuestNo, DateFrom, DateTo, RoomNo)     
    Guest(GuestNo,  GuestName, GuestAddress)
```

I want to List the details of all rooms at the Grosvenor Hotel,including the name of the guest staying in the room, if the room is occupied.

I'm okay with joining 2 tables in SQL but I don't know how to go about joining 4 tables.

My attempt would probably be:

```
SELECT Room.*, Guest.GuestName 
    FROM Room
    INNER JOIN Hotel, Booking, Guest
    ON Hotel.HotelName = "Grosvenor Hotel", Hotel.HotelNo = Room.HotelNo, Booking.GuestNo = Guest.GuestNo;
```

I think that's completely wrong but anyway, hopefully someone knows what I should be doing. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Do you would like to have a solution for sql-server or mysql. That are different thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT Room.*, Guest.GuestName 
FROM Room
INNER JOIN Hotel on Hotel.HotelNo = Room.HotelNo, 
inner join Booking on Booking.hotelno= Hotel.HotelNo
inner join Guest on Booking.GuestNo = = Guest.GuestNo
where Hotel.HotelName = "Grosvenor Hotel"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  select g.roomno, g.guestname 

  from hotel h join room r on h.hotelno = r.hotelno
   join booking b on b.hotelno=r.hotelno 
   join guest g on g.guestno=b.guestno

  where h.hotelname='Grosvenor Hotel';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this .. It Will help You

```
SELECT Room.*, Guest.GuestName FROM Room
INNER JOIN Hotel on Hotel.HotelNo = Room.HotelNo, 
join Booking on Booking.HotelNo= Hotel.HotelNo
join Guest on Booking.GuestNo = Guest.GuestNo
where Hotel.HotelName = "Grosvenor Hotel"
```